# Re-weight a data to match summary statistics of another dataset

Tags: r, meta-analysis, matching, adjustment

I am trying to conduct a matching-adjusted indirect comparison (MAIC) using R. The process is similar to propensity score weighting.

The process involves reweighting subjects in a population so that the summary of the covariates in this dataset match with the same covariates of aggregated data from another population.

I have inverse propensity score weights, but I'm struggling to make a start on applying these to the population so that they match the aggregate data. Does anyone know of any packages in R that would help, or have any experience of carrying out MAICs and can offer some tips? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for kind of weighted balance statistics for two populations (eg for treated and controls)?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I was looking to compare two different treatments from two separate sources.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into entropy balancing using the `WeightIt` package, which provides an interface to the `ebal` package. Entropy balancing is just like PS weighting except it guarantees exact balance on the covariates of your choice. What you will need to do is create a new data set (i.e., `newdata`) that is your sample population, and append to it one row containing the statistics from the other population. Then you'll need to add another variable (e.g., "sample") which represents which sample each row comes from; for the newly added row, this might have the value "1", and for the others (i.e., your original data set), this might have the value "0". In WeightIt, use the following code:

```
w <- weightit(sample ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = newdata, estimand = "ATT", method = "entropy")
```

To extract the weights, you can then do

```
weights <- w$weights[newdata$sample == 0]
```

These weights, when applied to your new data set, will make it appear like the other population you are trying to simulate.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to look into this as it seems to match what I'm looking to do. I had never heard of this package before, despite researching the problem for quite a while.

Comment: The package is fairly new (and is mine). But entropy balancing has been around since 2012 (see Hainmueller, 2012). Let me know if you have questions about the package.